# Python Positional Intersect

Tags: python

I am having trouble with my positional intersect method. I followed some algorithm the professor wanted us to use. A link will be provided below. I thought I was right but it returns an empty list.

http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/positional-indexes-1.html

For the assignment the professor wanted k to be 1

```
def phrase_intersect(list1, list2)
    answer = []
    i1 = 0
    i2 = 0
    pos1 = 0
    pos2 = 0

    while (i1<len(list1)) and (i2<len(list2)):
        if list1[i1] == list2[i2]:
            l = []
            pos1 = i1
            pos2 = i2
            while (pos1 < len(list1)):
                while (pos2 < len(list2)):
                    if abs(pos1 - pos2) <= 1:
                        l.append(pos2)
                    elif pos2 > pos1:
                        break
                    pos2 += 1
                while ((len(l) != 0) and (abs(l[0] - pos1) > 1)):
                    l.pop(0)
                for p in l:
                    answer.append(list1[i1],pos1,p)
                pos1 += 1
            i1 += 1
            i2 += 1
        elif list1[i1] < list2[i2]:
            i1 += 1
        else: 
            i2 += 1

    return answer
```

I assume it is some logic error but I am drawing a blank. All help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to mention what format the input is but here are some examples:
>>> phrase_intersect([[0, 1, 4], [1, 0], [10, 2, 3, 4]], \
                         [[0, 2, 6], [1, 2], [2, 0], [10, 1, 5]])                                                                                                            Output -> [[0, 2], [10, 5]]                                                                           >>> phrase_intersect([[1, 2]], [[1, 4]])
       Output -> []

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned about what data that you are passing to the function that you have coded.

Following program is about finding position intersect when the data is given in the format given in the link http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/positional-indexes-1.html

```
#Document Frequency 

document_frequecy_data_1 = { "word" : "to" ,
                             "frequency" : 993427,
                              "info" : 
                             [ { "document_id" :  1 ,
                                  "occurrence_count" :  6 ,
                                  "positions"   : [ 7, 18, 33, 72, 86, 231]
                                },
                                { "document_id" :  2 ,
                                  "occurrence_count" :  5 ,
                                  "positions"   : [ 1, 17, 74, 222, 255]
                                },
                                { "document_id" :  4 ,
                                  "occurrence_count" :  5 ,
                                  "positions"   : [ 8, 16 , 190, 429, 433]
                                },
                                { "document_id" :  5 ,
                                  "occurrence_count" :  2 ,
                                  "positions"   : [ 363, 367 ]
                                },
                                { "document_id" :  7 ,
                                  "occurrence_count" :  3 ,
                                  "positions"   : [ 13, 23, 191]
                                }
                             ]
                            }

document_frequecy_data_2 = { "word" : "be" ,
                             "frequency" : 178239,
                              "info" : 
                             [ { "document_id" :  1 ,
                                  "occurrence_count" :  2,
                                  "positions"   : [ 17, 25]
                                },
                                { "document_id" :  4 ,
                                  "occurrence_count" :  5 ,
                                  "positions"   : [ 17, 191, 291, 430, 434]
                                },
                                { "document_id" :  5 ,
                                  "occurrence_count" :  3 ,
                                  "positions"   : [  14, 19, 101 ]
                                }
                             ]
                            }



def pos_intersect(data_1, data_2, k =1):
    answer = []
    data_info_1 = data_1["info"]
    data_info_2 = data_2["info"]
    
    i = 0
    j = 0

    while ( i < len(data_info_1) and j < len(data_info_2)):
        document_id_1 = data_info_1[i]["document_id"]
        document_id_2 = data_info_2[j]["document_id"]
        if ( document_id_1 == document_id_2):
            pos_res_list = [] 
            pos_list_1 = data_info_1[i]["positions"]
            pos_list_2 = data_info_2[j]["positions"]

            k = 0
            
            while ( k < len(pos_list_1) ):
                l = 0
                while (l < len(pos_list_2)) :
                    distance =  abs(pos_list_1[k] - pos_list_2[l])
                    if ( distance <= k):
                        pos_res_list.append(l)
                    elif pos_list_2[l]  > pos_list_1[k]:
                        break
                    l = l + 1

                for item in pos_res_list:
                    distance =  abs(pos_list_2[item] - pos_list_1[k] )
                    if distance > k :
                        pos_res_list.remove(item)
                for item in pos_res_list:
                    answer.append({ "document_id" : document_id_1,  "position_data_1" : pos_list_1[k]  ,  "position_data_2" : pos_list_2[item] }  )
                
                k = k + 1

            i = i + 1
            j = j + 1
        else:
            if document_id_1 < document_id_2:
                i = i + 1
            else:
                j = j + 1

    return answer


results = pos_intersect(document_frequecy_data_1, document_frequecy_data_2, 4)
print("Results : ")
for res in results:
    print("Document id :" , res["document_id"] ,  " Position 1: " , res["position_data_1" ], " Position 2 :", res["position_data_2" ])
```